# Extracting substring from a column based on a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, csv

I have a simple table in SQL server as:

```
ID    NAMES

1     John;Betty;Dave;Bob

2     Mary;Raul;Felix
```

I wish to extract the 'First' string separated by ';' from the NAMES column. Output should be

```
ID  Names

1   John
2   Mary
```

Comment: Never, ever store data as ; separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string functions:

```
select t.*, left(names, charindex(';', names) - 1) as first_name
from mytable t
```

If you want to return the entire string in case there is no embedded `';'`, then:

```
select t.*, left(names, charindex(';', names + ';') - 1) as first_name
from mytable t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ef6c53f9a2af4d56980af01a3979c0f6)**:

```
select t.*, left(names, charindex(';', names + ';') - 1) as first_name
from (values 
    (1, 'John;Betty;Dave;Bob'), 
    (2, 'Mary;Raul;Felix'), 
    (3, 'foo')
) t(id, names)
```

```
id | names               | first_name
-: | :------------------ | :---------
 1 | John;Betty;Dave;Bob | John      
 2 | Mary;Raul;Felix     | Mary      
 3 | foo                 | foo
```

Comment: I would add a fail-safe ... just in case   eft(names, charindex(';', names+';') - 1)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti: I was testing that actually... And came up with the same solution as yours, just updated the answer.